# Can I visualize work of Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I mean - see in browser - what the element Jsoup read now.

It's maybe be helpful to see process of parsing.

Comment: No, it's not a part of the standard Jsoup library.

Comment: Jsoup will parse 99% of the HTML out there in < 1 second. What are you doing where visualizing this is going to help you?

Comment: I mean in debug view - see parsing of page, for example, for ten seconds or when I push button - highlight next element.